# this.props.navigation.navigate is not navigating to the correct screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I faced this weird situation where when I navigating from a screen to another, it navigating back to the previous screen that has been opened.

**Navigation expectation :**

`Layer 1 (screen A) > Layer 2 (screen B) > Layer 3 (screen C) > Layer 4 (screen D) > Layer 5 (screen B) > Layer 6 (screen C) > Layer 7 (screen D)`

and when `go back` button is clicked from each screen, it will be popped backwards

`Layer 7 > Layer 6 > Layer 5 > Layer 4 > Layer 3 > Layer 2 > Layer 1`

Instagram app is the good example for the navigation cycle.

**What my app faced :**

`Layer 1 (screen A) > Layer 2 (screen B) > Layer 3 (screen C) > Layer 4 (screen D) > Layer 2 (screen B) > Layer 3 (screen C)`

If you see from **Layer 4 (screen D)** navigating to **screen B** it should open it as **Layer 5** instead, but what happened was, it been opened as **Layer 2** which is jumping 2 layers back.

I am using `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')` to navigate to another screen.

**EDIT : SAMPLE CODE**

I have set a route in my app like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import ScreenA from 'app/views/ScreenA';
import ScreenB from 'app/views/ScreenB';
import ScreenC from 'app/views/ScreenC';
import ScreenD from 'app/views/ScreenD';

const Navigation = createStackNavigator({
    'PublicRoutes': {screen: ScreenA},
    'ScreenB':{screen: ScreenB},
    'ScreenC':{screen: ScreenC},
    'ScreenD':{screen: ScreenD},
});

export default createAppContainer(Navigation)
```

And this is the sample code for screens :

```
type Props = {};
export default class ScreenD extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB')}>
                    <Text>PRESS</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show me your stack setup code.

Comment: @hongdevelop I have added some code in my question. Thanks.

Comment: I want to see layers 4 and 5. where you have a problem

Comment: My screens all been imported into `route` file and registered in `createStackNavigator` like in the first code stack and the code structure for all of my screens are like in the second code stack. There is no difference in every screen.

Comment: I found a question while looking at the code to ask a question. Why is the routeName of Layer 5 and Layer 2 the same?

Comment: @hongdevelop it was because when I am opening `screen B`, I expect it to be the 5th layer been opened by using `this.props.navigation.navigate()`. But instead of opening it as the 5th layer, it been opened as 2nd layer. Doesn't matter what screen I'm opening, as long as it is using `this.props.navigation.navigate()` the screen should be opened as a new layer. Else I use `replace` or something like that. Aren't it so?

Comment: You can use this if you want to render the screen again.  `this.props.navigation.push('screenB')`

Comment: @hongdevelop Oh it works using `push`. Can you put it in your answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same `routeName`. The name must be set differently from screen to screen. `Navigation` does not distinguish it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import ScreenA from 'app/views/ScreenA';
import ScreenB from 'app/views/ScreenB';
import ScreenC from 'app/views/ScreenC';
import ScreenD from 'app/views/ScreenD';
import ScreenE from 'app/views/ScreenE';

const Navigation = createStackNavigator({
    'PublicRoutes': {screen: ScreenA}, // Layer 1
    'ScreenB':{screen: ScreenB}, // Layer 2
    'ScreenC':{screen: ScreenC}, // Layer 3
    'ScreenD':{screen: ScreenD}, // Layer 4
    'ScreenE':{screen: ScreenE}, // Layer 5
});
```

**ScreenD.js**

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenE')
```

You can use this if you want to render the screen again.

```js
this.props.navigation.push('screenB')
```

Comment: Solved my issue with `push`. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the render(){} outside the constructor?

Comment: Oh sorry, I set it wrongly in the question. I did a correction for it. My code set like in the new update I made in the question.